# raspberry Pi 2 connection to non encrypted Wifi

Tags: wifi, wireless-adapter

I want to connect my raspberry pi 2 to a non encrypted network named "xxxxxxx". 
How can i do it ? 
For an encrypted network i can simply add the credentials in a wpa_suuplicant.
But in my case i want to connect to a non encrypted network (**without password**).
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `iwconfig` and set your WiFi characteristics to the network.

For example:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 1 essid "My Network"
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

This hopefully will get you accessing the network. If you want to extract more details of the network, perform a network sweep:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep "My Network"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer: it return `Error for wireless request "set frequency (8B04): SET failed on device wlan0; operation not supported`

Comment: which adapter are you using ? can you update your question which what is stated in `lsusb` command? also I have updated the answer try following the step now.